# Is there a way to add a cleanup routine to a Future?

Tags: rust, async-await

Is there a way to add code to a `Future`/`async fn` in Rust such that it will always run when the execution of the `Future` is terminating, whether this is because the `Future` is being dropped or because it has finished normally?

Comment: What specifically needs to happen?  If you don't need async, manually implementing [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html) to handle this is pretty easy.

Comment: Can you "almost pseudocode" your use case?  And/or, just a rust snippet that highlights where you'd use this, and how you'd use it?  Might help get a better view of exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: The one thing that is always guaranteed to run are the `Drop` implementations of the captured objects. So you could move an object into the `async fn` and then perform your action in its `Drop` implementation. Of course you could also implement your own `Future` with a custom `Drop` function, I just wanted to mention an alternative.

Comment: Is this to ensure it's cancellation safe? If so, implementing `Drop` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this implemented by the [future-utils](https://crates.io/crates/future-utils) crate called [`Finally`](https://docs.rs/future-utils/latest/future_utils/struct.Finally.html) but it relies on an older version of the `Future` trait before it was stabilized in the standard library. I was bamboozled thinking it was the [futures-utils](https://crates.io/crates/futures-util) crate, which IS up to date, but doesn't have this functionality.

Regardless, here's an implementation that will call a function when a future is dropped:

```toml
[dependencies]
pin-project = "1.0.12"
```

```
//! on_drop.rs
use std::future::Future;
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Poll, Context};

use pin_project::{pin_project, pinned_drop};

#[pin_project(PinnedDrop)]
pub struct OnDrop<Fut, F> where F: FnOnce() {
    #[pin]
    future: Fut,
    drop_fn: ManuallyDrop<F>,
}

impl <Fut, F> OnDrop<Fut, F>
where F: FnOnce()
{
    pub fn new(future: Fut, drop_fn: F) -> Self {
        Self {
            future,
            drop_fn: ManuallyDrop::new(drop_fn),
        }
    }
}

impl<Fut, F> Future for OnDrop<Fut, F>
where 
    F: FnOnce(),
    Fut: Future,
{
    type Output = Fut::Output;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        this.future.poll(cx)
    }
}

#[pinned_drop]
impl<Fut, F> PinnedDrop for OnDrop<Fut, F>
where F: FnOnce()
{
    fn drop(self: Pin<&mut Self>) {
        let mut this = self.project();

        // SAFETY: we always construct `drop_fn` with a value and this is the
        // only place we take the value out of it, when the value is being
        // dropped.
        let drop_fn = unsafe { ManuallyDrop::take(&mut this.drop_fn) };
        drop_fn();
    }
}

pub trait FutureOnDropExt {
    fn on_drop<F: FnOnce()>(self, drop_fn: F) -> OnDrop<Self, F> 
    where 
        Self: Sized;
}

impl<Fut> FutureOnDropExt for Fut where Fut: Future {
    fn on_drop<F: FnOnce()>(self, drop_fn: F) -> OnDrop<Self, F> 
    where 
        Self: Sized
    {
        OnDrop::new(self, drop_fn)
    }
}
```

And can be used like:

```
//! main.rs
mod on_drop;
use on_drop::FutureOnDropExt;

fn main() {
    async { println!("this doesn't print since we don't poll") }
        .on_drop(|| println!("this does print when dropped"));
}
```

```
this does print when dropped
```

---

I took a quick look to see if anyone had suggested this for the [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate but didn't see anything relevant. If you have a genuine use-case for this, I'd suggest proposing such an adapter. Either it could be added in the future, or sparking the idea may find there is a flaw in the technique or a better solution to achieve your goals.

Comment: Could wrap the drop closure in `Option` and do `if let Some(drop_fn) = this.drop_fn.take()` to avoid the unsafe code

Comment: @Finomnis Oh definitely! Another safe option would be to use `Fn()` instead of `FnOnce()`. So if you were to copy this into a `#![forbid(unsafe_code)]` code-base then you'd need to make one of those changes. I wrote it this way because that's how I'd envision it being implemented on `FutureExt`, since you get the `FnOnce` guarantee without the space-cost of wrapping it in an `Option`.